# partial differentiation of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $a,b$ be constants satisfying $a^2+b^2=1.$ Let $f=f(x,y)$ be a twice differentiable function, and $u=ax-by$ and $v=bx+ay$. For the function $g$ defined by $g(x,y)=f(u,v)$, prove $g_{xx}(x,y)+g_{yy}(x,y)=f_{uu}(u,v)+f_{vv}(u,v)$

i was studying for my exams and i got stuck. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here... I can't even start.... a little help would be much appreciated :'(

Comment: In other words, $T$ is an orthogonal transformation and $(u, v) = T(x, y)$. Prove that if $g(x, y) = f(u, v)$, then $\nabla_{uv}^2 g = \nabla_{xy}^2 f$.

Comment: As that comment isn't very helpful for actually solving the problem (and only for learning more about related topics), here's a helpful hint... Can you apply the chain rule for partial derivatives to find $g_x$ in terms of $f_u$, $f_v$, $u_x$, and $v_x$? And similarly find $g_{xx}$ and $g_{yy}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the chain rule twice:

$$g_x = f_u u_x + f_v v_x= af_u + bf_v$$

$$g_{xx} = a(af_u + bf_v)_u + b(af_u + bf_v)_v = a^2f_{uu}+abf_{uv}+abf_{vu}+ b^2f_{vv}$$

$$g_y = f_u u_y + f_v v_y= -bf_u + af_v$$

$$g_{yy} = -b(-bf_u + af_v)_u + a(-bf_u + af_v)_v = b^2f_{uu}-abf_{vu}-abf_{uv}+ a^2f_{vv}$$

Now add.